# min(f(x)) is convex or concave based on type of f(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex

i have f(x) that is concave function. My question is g=min(f(x)) is concave or convex? And max(g) is concave or convex? there is a theorem for this?

[image]

Comment: What is g=min(f) - a number? But it sounds like g is meant to be a function. Either way, this question is a lot closer to Math than to Computational Science.

Comment: Optimization problems that involve minimizing a convex function or maximizing a concave function are called convex optimization problems.  If your problem is to maximize a convex function then it is a no convex optimization problem.

Comment: my problem is max g, where g=min(f(x)) , f(x) is concave, if i proof that g is concave then max g is a convex optimization as maximize concave.

Comment: Does $f$ have some parameter $a$ so that you're maximizing $\max_{a} \min_{x} f_{a}(x)$?

Comment: If $g=min_x(f(x))$, then $g$ is just a number as pointed out above. You can't *maximize* it -- it's just a number, there is nothing you can vary to optimize it. To optimize something, it must depend on some kind of variable that you can choose.

Comment: i add a picture, could you help me

Comment: @Maria Add formulas, not pictures. Explain all the symbols, especially if you have dangling variables like $t_k,p_k$.